# can't delete nested attributes child record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't delete nested attributes child record.
Article with Article_series is the model.
Here's the code.

## Model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles_article_series
  has_many :article_series, through: :articles_article_series

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles_article_series, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['article_id'].blank? && attributes['series_id'].blank? && attributes['num'].blank? }
```

## Controller

```
def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:article][:id])
    # article_series delete
    @article.articles_article_series.each do |series|
      series.mark_for_destruction
    end
    @article.save
```

Does anyone tell me why & how?

Comment: you really want to delete record or just want to "mark_for_destruction"

Comment: I really want to delete the record. But it seems like not working after `@article.save`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for 
`has_many :articles_article_series, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work. I only want to delete child record, not parent.

Comment: Could you provide some additional information, a little more specificity of the task you are trying to accomplish? I would love to help further with more info.

Comment: Great! But somehow I finally found how to fix it. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only array works 'mark_for_destruction'.

```
@article.articles_article_series.to_a.first.mark_for_destruction
```

Before, I did like below. It's so difficult to find the way to fix.

```
@article.articles_article_series.first.mark_for_destruction
```

Thanks for all contributes :)